# Select first element of a nested list of lists

Tags: aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to get the first element in each nested list in a list of lists in JMESpath. Specifically, I am trying variations on:

```
aws redshift-data get-statement-result \
  --id 0de36215-f1db-421f-8704-3242e1a03f21 \
  --query 'Records[][0]'
```

Unfortunately this results in the parent list being firstly flattened, and thus I get just the first element of the first list.

The input data (simplified) is:

```json
{   
    "Records": [
        [{"stringValue": "rdsdb"},{"etc": 1}],
        [{"stringValue": "testuser"},{"etc": 100}]
    ],
    "ColumnMetadata": [{"etc": true}],
    "TotalNumRows": 2
}
```

Given that input data, the output I would expect from that:

```json
[
    {"stringValue": "rdsdb"},
    {"stringValue": "testuser"}
]
```

How can I get the first element in each nested list in a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I gather from your comment, you over-simplified your example and you actually after a whole object, and not a single property.

With that requirement, you can achieve it using `[*]` instead of `[]`, as [the first one does not flatten projections, compared to the second one](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections).

So, given the JSON input:

```json
{   
    "Records": [
        [{"stringValue": "rdsdb", "some-property": "foo"},{"etc": 1}],
        [{"stringValue": "testuser"},{"etc": 100}]
    ],
    "ColumnMetadata": [{"etc": true}],
    "TotalNumRows": 2
}
```

The query:

```
Records[*][0]
```

Yields the expected:

```json
[
  {
    "stringValue": "rdsdb",
    "some-property": "foo"
  },
  {
    "stringValue": "testuser"
  }
]
```

---

Otherwise, you can filter out all the object in the array of array `Records` using a filter projection that would look if the key `stringValue` is not `null` with `[?stringValue]`

But because `[]` is creating a projection, as you raised, you have to [stop that projection first, with the pipe operator `|`](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filtering-and-selecting-nested-data), as explained in the linked documentation chapter.

So given:

```
Records[]|[?stringValue]
```

This yields the expected:

```json
[
  {
    "stringValue": "rdsdb"
  },
  {
    "stringValue": "testuser"
  }
]
```

Comment: This doesn't work and does not return "the first element in each nested list in a list of lists". Rather, it returns all objects in all lists containing a key `stringValue`.

Comment: Then you might have over simplified your JSON, if you test this on the [JMESPath page](https://jmespath.org/) against your input data, this yields what you were asking for.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I updated the answer, in regard to your comment